# Hello. Error running hello tensorflow program from tensorflow for dummies

Tags: tensorflow

Hello when I try to run an introductory program from the TENSORFLOW FOR DUMMIES BOOK in the anaconda shell, I receive the following error:

(tf) C:\Users\ME\TENSORFLOW\ch2>python hello_tensorflow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_tensorflow.py", line 10, in 
    msg = tf.string_join(['Hello ', 'TensorFlow!'])
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'string_join'

Now I receiev this error:
C:\Users\ME\TENSORFLOW\ch3>import tensprflow as tf
'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Something seems to tell me that tensorflow is not installed properly. If tensorflow stated that it was successfully installed why can'y I import tensorflo?

thank you
I received this when I installed tensor flow using the "pip3 install tensorflow" command on the command line:
I used the installation guide. I received this: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\program files\python36\Lib\site-packages\six.py'

thank you in advance

Comment: quoting from your question (import tensprflow as tf 'import').. are you importing it as tensprflow in the code as well? or this is just a typo in the question? I haven't used tensorflow in a while but I know that it used to have some problems with new versions of Python. I would start digging into that

Answer (score 0):

Try `tf.strings.join`instead if you are using TF 2+.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance prouast. I've always believed Australians are among the best people on earth !  Unfortunately I still receive errors when I change the code to tf.strings.join:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library

Comment: It sounds like tensorflow is not properly loaded or installed. Did you use the install guide?

Comment: I used the installation guide. I received a a new message entered above, thanks